# Jquery html pass a value as third parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Is there a way I can pass from an input html tag and append it to a link url ?

```
 <input type="text" name="job_card_id_payment"
        id="job_card_id_payment"
        class="job_card_id_payment form-control"/>
 <a class="btn btn-success pull-right" 
    id="submit_payment_link" 
    href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>operations/submit_payment">
   <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Submit Payment
 </a>
```

I want to pass the value from the  input name job_card_id_payment to the end of the link url so that it can be like this one :

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>operations/submit_payment/1
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to extract the value from `input` tag and update the URL:

```
$('#submit_payment_link').click(function(e) {
  // Getting input value.
  var value = $('#job_card_id_payment').val();
  // Getting current link URL.
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  // Checking for slash at the end and updating URL.
  href += ('/' == href.slice(-1) ? '' : '/') + value;
  // Setting updated URL.
  $(this).attr('href', href);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it via jQUery :

```
//get the value of your input
var myValue = $("#job_card_id_payment").val();
var myLink = $("#submit_payment_link");
//get the original url
var url = myLink.attr("href");
//modify the url
myLink.attr("href", url+"/"+myValue);
```

But I think you should use a regular form (containing that input) with a submit that sends that value to your page. That would be by-the-book.

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery Solution**

```
var id = $('#job_card_id_payment').val();
var link = $('#submit_payment_link');
var href = link.val();
var href += '/' + id;
link.attr('href', href);
```